# Get Max+1 values for every insert in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, max

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT ON ANIO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ANIOXCAP (ANCA_ID,ANCA_CAP,ANCA_ANIO)
  SELECT SIGUIENTE,CAPITULOS.CAPI_ID,:new."ANIO_ID" FROM CAPITULOS;
END;
```

Basically I have 30 entries in CAPITULOS. And for each insert in Anio, I need to add 30 entries. I read that I have to use secuences to manage MAX+1 but, how does the sequence know where to start, since when I create the sequence it starts at 1 and I already have around 400 entries (going from 1-400~)

By database ver is 11g

Comment: You shouldn't use a trigger for this. Triggers are not for inserting mass data into a different table upon which the data came in.  You should revisit your requirements on this.  As for sequences: just use START WITH to start it at a higher number than 1.

Comment: Not sure I understand. sequence values have no intrinsic meaning other than being unique per database.  You can create a sequence and specify what number is should start with.

Comment: Always remember to mention your **database version**. From 12c, Oracle  has introduced identity column. If you are on a release prior to 12c, then create a sequence with your desired value to start with. See my answer.

Comment: @Oldp; That is true, if you DO NOT use the CYCLE option of a sequence. If you do, major problems will occur at moment of cycle, because from that moment on, the sequence starts to give duplicate numbers. An interesting point here is (using CYCLE or not) : what is the maximum of my sequence ? What is the rough estimated amount of sequence I will EVER need ? If that is 200, and you have 7 trillion as max., that is OK. But, it can be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to configure a start value for the [SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314), then you need to have the **START WITH** clause.

For example,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_seq
 START WITH     400
 INCREMENT BY   1;
```

If you are on **Oracle 12c**, I recommend to use **Identity column** rather than the old **trigger + sequence** approach.

Comment: Apart from creating a sequence that starts at a given number, another method is to loop through the sequence, until a given value is reached. By means of getting Nextval, you're changing the value of the sequence, but there's no obligation to actually use any given number. What is good about this approach, is that you can use this system more than once : you can get a sequence to any number (higher than the actual number), but later on you can let a sequence advance any numbers you want (again, to values higher than the one already stored).